# EF & linq - many to many relationship

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I have 3 tables with a many to many relationship between them

User: Id (PK), Name

UserCourses: UserId (PK), CourseId (PK)

Courses: Id (PK), Name

I need to write a linq query to select all the courses name of user X and return in a IEnumerable but I can't get it to work.

EDIT:

```
public IEnumerable<Courses> GetCourses
        {
            get
            {
                return (from a in _entities.Users.Include("Courses")
                        where a.Id == this.Id
                        select a.Courses.AsEnumerable()
                        );
            }
        }
```

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I've just added the code

Comment: What's happening when you run this? Are you getting the wrong data back? Throwing an exception?

Comment: Error 31 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Data.Models.Courses>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Models.Courses>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: That's consistent with the nesting issue I observed below. Note the nested `< >` brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a little unclear about what's going wrong, but that looks like it would produce an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Courses>>` type. If you're looking for a **flattened** `IEnumerable<Courses>`, which I think you are, you need something like:

```
    public IEnumerable<Courses> GetCourses
    {
        get
        {
            var query = from a in _entities.Users.Include("Courses")
                        where a.Id == this.Id
                        select a;

            return query.FirstOrDefault().Courses;
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT:** To avoid a NullReferenceException, try this instead:

```
    public IEnumerable<Courses> GetCourses
    {
        get
        {
            var query = from a in _entities.Users.Include("Courses")
                        where a.Id == this.Id
                        select a.Courses; //note the difference

            return query.SelectMany(i => i);
        }
    }
```

Note that there are more than one ways to do this; for example, you could also use:

```
            var query = from a in _entities.Users.Include("Courses")
                        where a.Id == this.Id
                        select a;

            var user = query.FirstOrDefault();

            return user == null 
                      ? user.Courses
                      : null;
```

If the `SelectMany` version still causes a NullReferenceException, use this instead. I don't think it should, but I haven't tested it. You indicated that Rup's solution had done that, and he's using `SelectMany` in much the same way I am, so this last version plays it safe.

Comment: it doesn't allow me to use .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: What type is query - `IEnumerable<User>`? I'd have thought FirstOrDefault() would be OK, except in the null case - what error do you get? Would `return query.SelectMany(a => a.Courses);` work?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it does allow me to use FirstOrDefault(). Let me run this and see...

Comment: Hi Rup, this works, but only if there are courses associated with a user. otherwise, it throws an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."   is there any way around this? thanks

Comment: Hmm, that's odd - generally if you're doing this stuff still in the SQL layer you don't need to worry about null checking. You could try `.Where(a => a.Courses != null).SelectMany(a => a.Courses)` to see if that helps but I would still expect it to be doing this stuff in the database - it might be worth trying to figure out which operation triggered the switch to objects in your code. (P.S. since this isn't a reply to my answer you should write @ like Twitter - i.e. @Rup - so I get a notification of the reply. However your reply to my answer below generate notifications to me without the @ .)

Comment: @user441365: Oh, that makes sense. It's the `query.FirstOrDefault()`. FirstOrDefault will return `null` if it's an empty set. I'll edit this to take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

That more or less looks OK to me. Doesn't that work if you just drop the .AsEnumerable()? I don't think you need that.

I'm more comfortable with the LINQ extension method call syntax; I think the way to do this like that would be

```
var courses = _entities.Users.Include("Courses")
                       .Where(a => a.Id == this.Id)
                       .SelectMany(a => a.Courses);
```

with an extra `.Select(c => c.Name)` for just the course names.

Comment: No, it throws this error, with or without the AsEnumerable():        Error 31 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Data.Models.Courses>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Models.Courses>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: OK, sorry. I've picked a many-to-many relationship in my current project and this works OK, although it's one where the mapping shows up as 1-to-* in the properties designer - I'm not sure I've got a true * -to- * to play with here.

Comment: Found a * -to - * in my entity designer and this still works for me, sorry, for that relationship. Your error looks like you still have a List of Lists of Courses even after the SelectMany, though (!). I guess you could force your way through that with a second SelectMany although it would be better to understand where that's coming from.

Comment: Hi Rup, this indeed works, but as I said on another comment it breaks if no courses are assigned to a User. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
from b in _entities.Users.Include("UserCourses") on a.UserID equals this.ID
join c in _entities.Users.Include("Courses") on b.CourseID equals c.ID
select c.name
```

Comment: I suspect EF has absorbed UserCourses into the relationship - he'll only have one navigation property Courses

Answer (score 0):

Query the junction table directly with joins:

```
            var courses = (from uc in _entities.UserCourses
                           inner join c in _entities.Courses on uc.CourseId equals c.Id
                           inner join u in _entities.Users on uc.UserId equals u.Id
                           where uc.UserId equals u.Id
                           select c).ToList();
```